# Неправильная очистка памяти

Tags: c, linux, массивы, сокет

Не понял, почему все крашится на очистке arrayMacaddr. На другом форуме написали, что у меня бред написан насчет `hci_inquiry`. Хотелось бы, чтобы кто-то объяснил, что не так.

Как заменить массив arrayMacaddr, в котором 20 указателей на мак-адреса, на обычный массив?
И почему у меня не проходит чтение из сокета?

Просьба ответить хоть на что-то. )

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jansson.h>
#include <jansson_config.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
json_t *SearchBT();
int ConnectionDev();
void AutoInputPK();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ConnectionDev(SearchBT());
return (0);
}
```

//***_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_***__

```
int ConnectionDev(json_t *mac)//функция для подключения устройства
{
struct sockaddr_rc addr = {0};//мак устройства с рфкомм EC:FE:7E:11:85:1F
int s, status, counter;
const char *dest = {0};
size_t t = 0;
ize_t n = 0;

s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
t = json_array_size(mac);
for (n = 0; n < t; n++)
{
dest = json_string_value(json_array_get(mac, n));
str2ba(dest, &addr.rc_bdaddr);
}
AutoInputPK(dest);
//char text[20]={0};
status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
fcntl(s, F_SETFL, FNDELAY | fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0));
counter = write(s, "wboam1\r", 8);
//sleep(5);
//counter =read(s,text, 8);
if (counter > 0)
{
printf("\n received:\n [%s]", dest);
}

if (status == 0)
{
printf("\nYEP MF`s");
}

if (status < 0)
{    
perror("uh oh");
}
close(s);
return 0;
}
```

//***_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_***

```
json_t *SearchBT() //Функция для поиска BT устройства с возвратом его мак адреса
{
inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
int max_rsp = 255, num_rsp;
int dev_id, len = 8, flags;
int i;
char addrf[19] = {0};
char *arrayMacaddr[20] = {0}; 
dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH; 
ii = (inquiry_info *)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));
num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags); 
if (num_rsp < 0)
{
perror("hci_inquiry");
}
printf("all devices:");
for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++)
{
ba2str(&(ii + i)->bdaddr, addrf);
arrayMacaddr[i] = strdup(addrf);
printf("\n--[%s]", arrayMacaddr[i]);
}
free(ii);
json_t *asd, *as2;
as2 = json_array();
//цикл проверки мак адресов, с последующим удалением мак адрессов левых     устройств
for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++)
{
char str2 [8] = "EC:FE:7E";
if (strncmp(arrayMacaddr[i], str2, 8) == 0)
{
asd = json_string(arrayMacaddr[i]);
json_array_append(as2, asd);
free(arrayMacaddr);
}
}
return (as2);
}
```

//***_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_******_***

```
void AutoInputPK(char *dest) //функция автоматического ввода пин кода из симпл агент
{    
char *macAddrs = dest;
char *cmdTemp = " bluez-simple-agent hci0 ";
char cmd[50];
sprintf(cmd, "%s%s", cmdTemp, macAddrs);
FILE *ptr;
ptr = popen(cmd, "w");
pclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: А где отступы? Отформатируй код, если хочешь чтобы его кто-то читал.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, как с `hci_inquiry`, а вот

```
max_rsp = 255,
```

и

```
char *arrayMacaddr[20]
```

как-то IMHO плохо стукуется, да и сама идея передавать массив указателей (это я про список MAC) через JSON отдает бредом.

---

Мне кажется, что надо выделить массив указателей размером `num_rsp + 1` malloc-ом, потом переписать в него все strdup-ы подходящих MAC, завершить его NULL (в стиле `argv[]`) и дальше таскать уже его.

**Обновление**

Если чисто формально исправлять ошибку, то замените

```
free(arrayMacaddr);
```

в последнем цикле на

```
free(arrayMacaddr[i]);
```

причем вынесите его из-под

```
   if (strncmp(arrayMacaddr[i], str2, 8) == 0) {
      ...
```

т.к. в предыдущем цикле Вы заполняете его

```
for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++) {
  ba2str(&(ii + i)->bdaddr, addrf);
  arrayMacaddr[i] = strdup(addrf);
}
```

для всех MAC (а не только интересных Вам).

Сам массив освобождать нельзя, т.к. Вы *не выделяли* под него память `malloc`-ом.

Comment: мне сказали делать через json,я делаю=)

Comment: @kvars232, Обновил ответ